# How to fetch form data and show it to my page?

Tags: plugins, forms

I'm new to wordpress, & trying to create a simple form from of my use, and wanna do it by plugins . so I created a plugin for that but that is not showing the values of my form.

there is a option also that, sometime it is showing the value on the top of the form, and the body part is showing 404 error page. 
please help to to create a form and fetching the value from it in OOP style.

I've written this part of the code

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['mail'];
echo $name . ' ' . $password;

function show_form( $atts ){
   $form_details="";
   // get attibutes and set defaults
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'name',
                'value' => 'Submit'
       ), $atts));
    // Display info 

    $form_details = '<form name = "myform" action "" method = "POST">';
    $form_details .= '<input type = "text" name = "name" value=""/>';
    $form_details .= '<input type = "text" name = "mail" value="" />';
    $form_details .= '<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Save"/>';
    $form_details .= '</form>';

    return $form_details;
}
add_shortcode('form', 'show_form');
```

and if you can suggest me any tutorial or book I'll be grateful to you .! Thank You .!

Comment: `name` is a WordPress query var, use more unique form field names.

Comment: [This page](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars#Query_variables) lists the public and private variable names you shouldn't use for form field names.